# TPT Script to ignore comma delimeter in double quote

Tags: shell, unix, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

> I have written a TPT Script to load csv file to teradata

```
A,   B,   C,   D

1,"hELL,O", 345,,, ME
2,"HELLO,34" 456,,, REC
3,"QWERTY,45", 456,,, WER
```

> Column B is having double quote and comma as well. I would like to ignore that comma inside double quote

I am using below attributes in tpt. Please suggest if it can be handle in TPT Script or need to do shell command in csv file (sed,awk command to deal with it)

`````
    (
      VARCHAR DirectoryPath = '/home/xyz/',
      VARCHAR FileName = @file_name,
      VARCHAR Format = 'Delimited',
      VARCHAR OpenMode = 'Read',
      VARCHAR TextDelimiter = ',',
      VARCHAR NullColumns = 'Y',
      INTEGER SkipRows = 1,
      VARCHAR SkipRowsEveryFile = 'Y'
)````

Unix Command, that I tried to replace comma with pipe and to ignore comma in double quotes

````awk 'BEGIN { FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; OFS="|" } $1=$1' $FILE_NAME_OUT1 > $FILE_NAME_OUT2
`````

It is not working, it is removing the column field (comma ,)

For example:-

```
A,   B,   C,   D

1|"hELL,O"| 345| ME
2|"HELLO,34" 456| REC
3|"QWERTY,45"| 456| WER
```

Please suggest on this.

Comment: Your example is unclear. Perhaps it would help if you show what values you want to be loaded, not just the "wrong" results.

Comment: Well, you didn't tell TPT that you have quoted data, you didn't set `QuotedData='Optional'` / `OpenQuoteMark='"'`